# Find the indefinite integral $\int \left(k+2\right)^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^{k+2}dt$

Tags: integration, summation, indefinite-integrals

I need to find the indefinite integral
\begin{align}I&=\int \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(k+2\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^{k+2}dt.\end{align}
It is the result of removing the first two terms from a logarithm Taylor series (they were integrable). Now I need to evaluate this integral/summation. Any ideas? (And this isn't a homework problem, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** That is just:
$$ \int\left(-\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}+\log(1+t^2)\right)\,dt = C-3t+3\arctan(t)+t\log(1+t^2).$$

Comment: I can't quite make the connection. I see Wolfram Alpha outputs something similar for the integrand (summation). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+infinity+1%2F%28k%2B2%29*%28t^2%2F%281%2Bt^2%29%29^%28k%2B2%29%29 (I've tried posting the link but it doesn't all get recognized)

Comment: @jm324354: please leave WA to write any mess it likes. Here we are simply exploiting $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{w^k}{k}=-\log(1-w)$ and integration by parts.